# LibreOffice Impress importing EPS images

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice, eps

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 x64 Desktop as OS.
Trying to prepare a slideshow, when adding .eps image drawings to a slide there is no problem at all. But when i hit F5 to start slide show, slide that includes .eps image does not shown in output. Nothing just an empty screen appears. Althoug i have an external monitor, current slide does not shows .eps imported image but next slide area shows it.

Also tried to with unchecking Tools > Options > LibreOffice > View > "Use hardware acceleration".

Nothing changed.

Here is a screen shot of my outputs. On the right is presentation output, on the left is presentation helper screen.

http://oi57.tinypic.com/2rp2qa0.jpg

Both Slides included .eps image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `Imagemagick` installed try to convert the eps file in another format ( e.g. png).

```
   convert mypic.eps mypic.png
```

If the problem is related to internal command of the eps file you should overcome it.

If you need high definition try

```
  convert -density 600 mypic.eps -resize 1024x1024 mypic.png
```

Change value for density in 150 300 600, or size (instead of 1024x1024) as needed

Comment: Although it looks like a workaround. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. If it is a vectorial eps you can convert in SVG to avoid to be annoyed by problem related to density and relative size. 
I experienced several problem with eps file in Impress. It should be linked with "what is inside" the eps,how it was generated, by which program and with which options, and under which operative system. You can make and idea of how is your eps file reading it, if it's a sequence of readable commands or if there's some binary block. It happened too that the background become transparent from white or that palette was not the same if you open with other prog.

Comment: BTW when you will need it is wise to have a pdf copy of your work. You lose animated effects but you earn in compatibility. Pay attention if you want to save the presentation in a different format. Change the type from the menu the and not directly changing the extension after the filename(e.g form presentation.odp to presentation.xls).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Seems to be a problem with the (actual) version of LibreOffice in Ubuntu 14.04. I solved it updating LibreOffice to Versión: 4.3.0.4 using the code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice libreoffice-kde
```

according to [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice).

Comment: Perhaps add a link to the bug report (possibly [this](https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62038) one?) or source for the problem with the "actual" version in Ubuntu?